# Parsing the Xml data in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, wsdl

I am beginner to iphone. My requirement is to invoke the sap webservice in iphone.I got the result data which is in xml form.The result is to be in NSString which is of Xml form.Then how to get that result into the array in xcode.Please help me.

Comment: <"<ZmaterialList><Matkl>00320</Matkl></ZmaterialList>",
    "<ZmaterialList><Matkl>0004</Matkl></ZmaterialList>",
    "<ZmaterialList><Matkl>001</Matkl></ZmaterialList>",                   In this the data is displayed but extract only 00320,0004,001 plz give me solution

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great library on [GitHub-XML to NSDictionary](https://github.com/bcaccinolo/XML-to-NSDictionary) 
It isn't quite an `NSArray` but xml files are rarely just Arrays, so this provides an intermediate, dictionaries when needed, arrays if possible.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can use `NSXMLParser` for this purpose, read through the delegate methods in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

**2**. This question is pretty repetitive, you could have just googled "Parsing the Xml data in iPhone" or "Parsing the Xml data using xCode" you would have got loads of results. Go trhough this ->
http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/
 and maybe this-> http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/

**3.** Next time please do search.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite general and it's difficult to give you a specific answer.

Here some guidelines to consume web services in iOS.

First, you need to have a mechanism that helps you to consume the ws. To do it, you can use `NSUrlConnection` class (see [NSURLConnection Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) or use a the ASIHttpRequest framework (see [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)). In this manner you can make requests and dowload response messages.

Since you use soap messages, you have first to create the request message manually. You can use class method of `NSString` `stringWithFormat` or use `ASIFormDataRequest` class of ASIHttpRequest framework.

Finally, if you receive a message that is like the following you posted in your comment, you need to parse it. Remember that is a soap message and it doesn't have only your tags. To do it, you can use `NSXMLParser` class (see [NSXMLParser Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) or use GDataXML parser (see [how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)).

Out there there are plenty of tutorials or posts on how to "consume web services on iOS". You can find them. In addition, there are also some kits that, taken the your service, create class wrappers to consume your services. In this case you don't need to create or parse manually masseges.

A last remark. When you need to consume data taken from a service, maybe a REST architecture could be easier to set up.

Hope it helps.